# How to generate a unique random number based on the load generator instance?

Tags: jmeter

We have 2 load generators (slaves) running. When the search results are displayed, I am trying to pick a random record to do further processing so I used ${__threadNum} in ‘match no’ of JSON extractor, but the same record (because of threadnum function)  is picked for both the instances of the generator.  I used random variable from 1 to 30 but sometimes the same number is taken for both the load generators.

Is there a way to pass a unique random number (like depending on the load generator machine) and get a unique record for processing?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter slaves no nothing about other online slaves, the only thing you can do is to grant an unique number to a particular slave either by putting it to *user.properties* file or passing it via `-J` command-line argument.

Like:

1. For the first slave:

   ```
   jmeter-server.bat -Jslave=1
   ```
2. For the second slave:

   ```
   jmeter-server.bat -Jslave=1
   ```
3. etc.

The property can be read using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and you will be able to use it as prefix, postfix, offset, [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) value, match number, or whatever.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)